# What is the way to setup Sail from a cloned Laravel project that already uses sail?

Tags: laravel, wsl-2, laravel-sail

The past few years I haven't been able to find the easiest way to clone a project from github and setup laravel sail on WSL2. The goal is to download the project and setup sail so it creates the correct dockerized mysql instance and database (and fills it in the .env), just like it does when installing a new laravel project.

I have tried the following approaches

- Copying sail files from other project
- Creating new laravel project and overwriting it

Comment: What issues are you having? You should just need to clone the repository (a normal git action) and just run `composer install`. That should download Laravel Sail if it is in the `require-dev` section. Then you have to configure it, writing the right content inside the `.env`, but there is no "automatic" .env creation and population. You have to set it up. Could you explain what errors or issues you are having?